# Hangfire - .net core web api - IIS Implementation Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I got an error hangfire implementation when I try to publish the web api on web server IIS. (WServer 2012) It was work on locally when I start on my computer host on IIS express. It was working well, I see my jobs on dashboard. I use the same connection strings on web server db, but it wasn't work on web server. The error is like that;

> **Category: Hangfire.Processing.BackgroundExecution EventId: 0**
>
> **Execution BackgroundServerProcess is still in the Failed state for 00:00:30.0352717 due to an exception, will be retried no more than in
>   00:00:15**
>
> **Exception:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'ABC SERVER'**.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

In ConfigureServices() method;

```
services.AddHangfire(_ => _.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireDbConn"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true
            }));
```

In Configure() method;

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs");
 app.UseHangfireServer();
```

What is the difference between same db connection, local pc debug mode works fine but publishing on web server, I got an login failed error from web server ?

Is there any solutions for that ? Thanks for all supports.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2029983)

Comment: I downvoted, because the [code is posted as images instead of text](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: The bolded message is pretty clear - the wrong account or password was used. None of those images shows the connection string or the users in the database. Perhaps the *wrong* database is used? Or the account doesn't exist on the production server?

Comment: I use same conn strings, it exist on the prod server also. I didn't catch that point actually, my db conn is on web server and it was work on my local running successfully when publishing on web server with same conn string, it returns that  Login failed for user 'ABC SERVER'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for my problem. Actually, I find my mistake point of implementation. It is about the connection **user grant and auth** informations. In Hangfire Sql Server config page has a solution for my problem. I create a new user for Hangfire. Then, define the auth and grant operations for this user. After that, I delete **trusted connection** definition from my conn string. Now, it is working.

```
CREATE USER [HangFire] WITH PASSWORD = 'strong_password_for_hangfire'
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE [name] = 'HangFire') EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [HangFire]')
GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[HangFire] TO [HangFire]
GO

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [HangFire]
GO
```

For more : https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html

Thanks for everyone!